# Oracle Apex - APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE Column Headers

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm inserting rows into an empty standard table using the APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE option (csv).
Issue is, my table headers are as follows:

```
column_1
column_2
column_3
```

and so on...
I'm trying to figure out the way of updating my table headers using the user selected file.
For example:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using the parser?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "table headers"? do you want to map the csv columns with your table? or do you want to update the final table columns?

Comment: Thank you. I want to update my current header column names with new user-defined column names.

Comment: Without losing the data already stored in your table. Right?

Comment: yes, I basically have a basic table with lots of columns (col001, col002, col003, etc) and need to update its headers based on whatever the user decides (once the user defined headers are not longer needed I would rename headers back to what they were originally)